# Mapping Index to a String in C

Tags: c, strings, linux, constants

Please excuse my potentially noob-ish question.  I haven't touched strings in C (or C in general) in a while, and I seem to recall there being different ways you can return a C string from a function (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25798977/1575353)).

I am currently implementing a weird driver API that I inherited. Long story short, I get passed in a "device index", and then return the device name that will be used to `open()` the device.

Here is my implementation:

```
static const char* getDeviceName(uint8_t device_index) {
  static const char* const device_names[] =
    {"", "/dev/some_device", "/dev/some_other_device", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
  if (device_index > 8) {
    return "";
  } else {
    return device_names[device_index];
  }
}
```

Long story short, I am provided an index (as a `uint8_t` for some reason) and then need to convert it to a string.  As such, I create a constant array of constant strings, which is static.  Note that many of these indexes are empty since they currently do not map to a device, but may in the future.

If the device index is out of bounds, I return the empty string.  If the index is in bounds, I index into my constant array and return that value.

Since my C is rusty, I'm wondering if any of the above is UB, or if there are better ways of doing this.  I know I can have the function return `void` and have the caller pass in a `char*` for me to populate, but I think the above is the cleanest way, since I can do things like "`open(getDeviceName(index));`".

In addition to my questions about UB, I also wanted to make sure that the code is `const` correct.

At any rate, let me know your thoughts.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You probably know that the `static` in the function declaration means something different to the `static` of `device_names`, but in case you don't: make sure that the API you're implementing doesn't require your function to have external linkage, or else remove the `static` from the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is completely safe and free of undefined behavior.

You have used `const` wherever it is useful and good style.

That's great. :)

One little source of confusion, though. The list of device names contains 9 entries, but the code compares something with an 8. This 8 is confusing since the *last valid index* in an array is just an implementation detail. (In other programming languages like Lua or Pascal, it could be different.) Contrary, the *number of devices* is more interesting to any reader. Therefore, readers expect to read that number. Whatever number you write in the code, make sure it's an *interesting* number.

Therefore, it's better to use the idiomatic code below:

```
size_t size = sizeof device_names / sizeof device_names[0];
if (device_index < size) {
    return device_names[device_index];
}
return "";
```

This code doesn't give any clue about the actual number of devices, which makes the code more robust when a device name is added to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm comparing against 8 since I have 9 entries and that's the maximum index I can use into the device_names array to extract a string.  I like the idiomatic suggestion though.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the suggestion, I integrated it into my answer.